# Insert textual instructions with the google map API

Tags: ios, google-maps

I use the google maps API to trace the route between two points, my code is this :

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%f,%f&daddr=%f,%f&hl=fr&output=embed&om=5",latUtilisateur,longUtilisateur,latStation,longStation];

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

However, this didn't has the textual instructions feature. Am i missing some parameters in the request above or something else?

Answer (score 0):

The output=embed parameter is resulting in the full screen map. You can try a couple of alternatives:

- For the standard map/directions page.

  http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Sydney&daddr=Brisbane&hl=fr&output=html&om=5
- For a mobile friendly directions
  page. This version includes links to
  static maps for each step of the
  journey.

  http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Sydney&daddr=Brisbane&hl=fr&output=mobile&om=5